# WinForm form size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a WinForms dashboard app for work and I am trying to design the UI to fit the UHD screen (3840x2160) that the dashboard will be run on once complete. The problem is that the computer I'm working on (and all the other PCs in the company) are full HD. I know about the implemented limitations of the form size and not being able to set the height or width of the form larger than +12 on top of my screen size, but designing on the screen that the dashboard will run on isn't an option for me, so I need a workaround.

What I tried so far is setting the AutoScoll property to true, as seen suggested in other threads, but that only creates scroll bars during RunTime, not design.
What I found weird is that, even though on every post regarding form size I came across it was mentioned that you cannot go more than 12 pixels over your screen size, for some reason when I tried resizing my form to 3840x2160, this set itself to 3840x1100, which I found weird and I can't seem to find a way to extend the height as well.

Comment: _"designing on the screen that the dashboard will run on isn't an option for me"_ yes it is. Although there are practical solutions like zooming out your screen res, getting a bigger screen to match your customer implementation is usually the cheapest. Grab an old TV if you need to, but time is money, you have spent more time on this post and waiting for a response than it would cost to get the right monitor. If you are a sub contractor, make it part of the contract, make the customer contribute if you need to.

Comment: ^ Seriously, that.

Comment: The closer your test-systems are to the real hardware the more bugs you can find and fix. This might be difficult if you have really expensive hardware, but a screen is not *that* expensive. You also need to consider and test with the various scaling options in windows.

Comment: I'm not a subcontractor, I'm just an employee doing an extra project, I only have VS installed on a single PC in the office and I can't just unplug it and go to the large monitor, as the systems department have strict rules regarding changing PC locations and such, so as I said, not an option.

Comment: Do you have an NVidia graphics card? Recent drivers have a feature called "Dynamic Super Resolution" which you can use to make Windows think the monitor resolution is higher than it actually is, and then the graphics card will (intelligently) resample the graphics down to the actual monitor resolution. (I think AMD also have a similar feature, but I don't know what that's called.)

Comment: Well, management is as a rule quite dumb and incompetent. But, with a price tag of 200$ for an UHD monitor you may be able to convince them that this will immediately save money, which is the only thing they at least __might__ understand.

Comment: Create a user control. Set the size. Then on run time add to the form. (I don't think it is any good to designe for 4k in two 2px monitor)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum form size is controlled by the [Form.SetboundsCore method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/5caee25123567f7b.html).  The relevant code in this method in as follows:

```
        // Enforce maximum size...
        //
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal
            && (this.Height != height || this.Width != width)) {

            Size max = SystemInformation.MaxWindowTrackSize;
            if (height > max.Height) {
                height = max.Height;
            }
            if (width > max.Width) {
                width = max.Width;
            }
        }
```

[SystemInformation.MaxWindowTrackSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.maxwindowtracksize) is the limiting value and this changes based on the computer's configuration.

One way to deal with this built-in limitation is to define a class that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form and override the SetWindowsCore method to allow for values that exceed MaxWindowTrackSize.  It is also necessary to handle the [WM_GETMINMAXINFO message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo) in the Form's WndProc method.

I originally posted this approach on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1650/NET-Core-and-Framework?df=90&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Compact&select=4599323&tid=4598385), but that implementation was in VB.Net.  The code below is a C# translation of that original code.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FormWithDesignSize : Form
{
    private const Int32 DefaultMax = 10000; //set this to whatever you need

    private Int32 _MaxDesignWidth = DefaultMax;
    private Int32 _MaxDesignHeight = DefaultMax;

    [Category("Design"), DisplayName("MaxDesignWidth")]
    public Int32 aaa_MaxDesignWidth //Prefix aaa_ is to force Designer code placement before ClientSize setting
    {
        get // avoids need to write customer serializer code
        {
            return _MaxDesignWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            _MaxDesignWidth = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("Design"), DisplayName("MaxDesignHeight")]
    public Int32 aaa_MaxDesignHeight //Prefix aaa_ is to force Designer code placement before ClientSize setting
    {
        get // avoids need to write customer serializer code
        {
            return _MaxDesignHeight;
        }
        set
        {
            _MaxDesignHeight = value;
        }
    }


    protected override void SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        if (this.DesignMode)
        {
            // The Forms.Form.SetBoundsCore method limits the size based on SystemInformation.MaxWindowTrackSize

            // From the GetSystemMetrics function documentation for SMCXMINTRACK: 
            //   "The minimum tracking width of a window, in pixels. The user cannot drag the window frame to a size 
            //    smaller than these dimensions. A window can override this value by processing the WMGETMINMAXINFO
            //    message."
            // See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

            // This message also appears to control the size set by the MoveWindow API, 
            // so it is intercepted and the maximum size is set to MaxWidth by MaxHeight
            // in the WndProc method when in DesignMode.

            // Form.SetBoundsCore ultimately calls Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore that calls SetWindowPos but, 
            // MoveWindow will be used instead to set the Window size when in the designer as it requires less
            // parameters to achieve the desired effect.

            MoveWindow(this.Handle, this.Left, this.Top, width, height, true);
        }
        else
        {
            base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        const Int32 WMGETMINMAXINFO = 0x24;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (this.DesignMode && m.Msg == WMGETMINMAXINFO)
        {

            MINMAXINFO MMI = new MINMAXINFO();
            // retrieve default MINMAXINFO values from the structure pointed to by m.LParam
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, MMI);

            // reset the ptMaxTrackSize value
            MMI.ptMaxTrackSize = new POINTAPI(_MaxDesignWidth, _MaxDesignHeight);

            // copy the modified structure back to LParam
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(MMI, m.LParam, true);
        }

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class MINMAXINFO
    {
        public POINTAPI ptReserved;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxSize;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxPosition;
        public POINTAPI ptMinTrackSize;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxTrackSize;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINTAPI
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;

        public POINTAPI(Int32 X, Int32 Y)
            : this()
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "(" + X.ToString() + ", " + Y.ToString() + ")";
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 nWidth, Int32 nHeight, bool bRepaint);

}
```

Add the above code to your project and perform a build.  Then you can add an "Inherited Form" based on FormWithDesignSize.